# Is there any way to give this sharp property for custom font in css file or else?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using one custom font file in css, but that font not showing sharp like PSD. In PSD for that use antialiased as 'sharp'. In HTML page its looks blur vibrating font. I want to give sharpness to font with CSS or else in HTML.

I have already tried '-webkit-font-smoothing' property in css, but not get any changes in font.

Is there any way to give this sharp property for custom font in css file or else?

Answer (score 0):

Not true antialiasing, but you could use `text-shadow` or `filter: drop-shadow()` to try and smooth out the edges a bit... (`text-shadow` is more widely supported)

Examples:

```
.filter-antialias{
    -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    -moz-filter:drop-shadow(0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    -ms-filter:drop-shadow(0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    -o-filter:drop-shadow(0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
    filter:drop-shadow(0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
}

.shadow-antialias{
    text-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But i tried with this solution it doesn't work. I want to make custom font character board sharp and with this solution its still showing vibrating text.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for MAC OS.

`-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;`